# Undefined method `assistants' for ActiveRecord_Relation - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create a controller with an action to generate reports in excel, in my variable of intance I am getting the event that I am going to generate the report and I need that by means of that variable of instance I can search in its relations of the event.

I understand that it is a relationship problem but I do not need a model for this, is there a way I can solve my problem?

event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assistants
end
```

In my controller:

```
class Admin::ReportAssistantsByEventsController < ApplicationController
  let :ADMINISTRATOR, :all
  include Admin::ReportAssistantsByEventsHelper

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: ReportAllAssistantsDataTable.new(view_context)}
    end
  end

  def assistants_report
    @event_report = Event.where(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {render xlsx: 'report_all_assistants', :filename => "#{@event_report.name}.xlsx", layout: false, disposition: "attachment"}
    end
  end

end
```

In my herlper:

```
def data_assistants
    assistants = @event_report.assistants
    assistants.each do |assistant|

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
@event_report = Event.where(id: params[:id])
```

Is returning an `ActiveRecord_Relation`. Which, as the error indicates, does not respond to `assistants`. If you want `@event_report` to be an `Event`, then do:

```
@event_report = Event.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

Or:

```
@event_report = Event.find_by(id: params[:id])
```